# Practical home stone grinding

Tags: coffee, grinding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I grind coffee without a coffee grinder?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28951/how-can-i-grind-coffee-without-a-coffee-grinder)

I like my coffee super-fine.

I've had some luck with using regular coffee grinders and running it for a long time, but I'd like to explore (possibly manual) alternatives.  There are 2 reasons I want to try the manual alternative:

1)  Electric coffee grinders are **extremely noisy**.  This makes it kind of impractical to grind coffee at odd hours (which I love to do)

2)  My electric coffee grinder seems to be wearing pretty fast.

I tried the [Kyocera "Hario Skerton" grinder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001802PIQ) which was eah.  It's a bit fragile, and when trying to get a fine grind you get a lot of crunching of the ceremic plates, which again will pretty much destroy it really fast.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Asking about better manual grinders or if there's a way to practically home stone grind short of dropping beans in the backyard and rolling stones around

Comment: You might want to edit the main question to make that clear, in case folks don't come down to the comments.

Comment: What kind of coffee do you make and use to make it? What kind of electric grinder are you currently using?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably mortar and pestle:

[image: mortar and pestle]

I've never used one for coffee until just now and it didn't take long to grind up a scoop of beens into a very fine powder.  When searching for a picture, I found lots of references to mortar and pestle being used for Turkish coffee, so super-fine seems to be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turkish coffee is made from super fine grounds, boiled together with the water in a small kettle (ibrik). The grinders are typically hand cranked, c.f.

[Turkish Coffee Grinder (Amazon)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001B1AGCO)